# What part of the browser is typically attacked?

Tags: web-browser, browser-extensions

Pretty sure that browsers are compromised most often through their plugins, at least, that's what I keep reading.  So, then, does that mean the browser itself has vulnerabilities, and the plugins are just the vector to get at the browser's vulnerabilities?

Comment: _The human user_ is the part which is most often compromised.

Comment: Targeting plugins has the advantage that these often have vulnerabilities which aren't tied to a specific web browser.